# Topology or jar specific logger configuration for storm (>0.9)

Tags: logging, logback, apache-storm

I am using storm version 0.9.1. I am facing an issue with configuring the logging that happens when a topology runs. By default storm logs all the logs to worker-.log using the logback configuration specified in cluster.xml. I would like to have topology specific logs which should be able to write to a different log location and also be able to configure the log level for these logs. Is it possible to do this without changing cluster.xml ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem?

Comment: Nope didn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to official documentation no other ways there. The logs are configured only in the ***$STORM_HOME/logback/cluster.xml*** (since 0.9). The main problem is that **logviewer daemon** depends on that file to be able to find and display worker logs. Overriding it would break the log viewer functionality.